# Cordova Image Picker Returning Temp URL From Cache Folder Where Images Are Not Present In It

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native

Not able to get the right image url when I select the images from the android device, I am able to get the temp image url from the cache where there is no original imaged copied to it.

The Url which I got from the plugin looks like this.

"file:///data/user/0/com.myapp.dev/cache/tmp_20180118_125700267959888.jpg"

Is there any way to get the original image path or the temp url itself where the duplicate image is present in it?

Plugin URL : https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-imagePicker.git

Plugin Version :1.1.1

Answer (score 0):

As reported in git repository readme:

> > Note for Android Use   **The plugin returns images that are stored in a
> >     temporary directory**. These images will often not be deleted
> >     automatically though. The files should be moved or deleted after you
> >     get their filepaths in javascript.

Anyway i think you need to edit source of plugin to return original image path in javascript callback.

Comment: I got your point, But probelm is whatever the temp image url which plugin is returning on selection the image is not valid, when I bind the url to the image source tag I do get error saying file not found. When I did the cross check in app cache folder the image is not preset. Is there any solution for it?