# Ionic - Ios - Cordova File Plugin - Error

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, ionic-native, cordova-plugin-file

I am developing a hybrid app targeting iOS & Android. I had to implement a photo-uploader so I implemented it through `ImagePicker` & `File` Cordova Plugins. I tested it on Android and everything was okay.

The problem is when I test it for iOS I get the image URIs through `ImagePicker` but `File` throws the following error:

> [error] - ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise):
> FileError: {"code":5,"message":"ENCODING_ERR"}

I have seen plenty of issues related to this error but all of them are related to Android while I have a problem with iOS. I understand that is a really complex issue so if anyone could give me any piece of advice, I would be grateful.

More details about the issue:

```
this.imagePicker
  .getPictures({
      maximumImagesCount: 1,
  })
  .then(async (result : string[]) => {
      let file = 'file://' + result[0];
      let path = file.substring(0, file.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
      this.image = await this.file.readAsDataURL(path, file): // Line which throws the exception
  });
```

PS: I've tried adding 'file://' in all the ways I could imagine =)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, have you tried print the path? do you test it with real device?

Comment: Yep, I printed it out and this was the result: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/45B44DDA-83F5-44AD-8060-D144031CB3CF/tmp/cdv_photo_004.jpg

Comment: I don't understand why ImagePicker is giving me a tmp directory when actually it must be persistent as the gallery photos are, aren't it?

Comment: looks like this is cordova image picker plugin problem, another man report this too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48380996/cordova-image-picker-returning-temp-url-from-cache-folder-where-images-are-not-p

Answer (score 0):

Thanks both of you who helped, I fixed my problem through changing the outputType to 1 (base64 dataURL) instead of 0 (URI).

This is the code that fixed my bug.

```
this.imagePicker
    .getPictures({
      outputType: 1,
    })
    .catch((e) => alert(e))
    .then(async (results: string[]) => {
         this.image = "data:image/jpg;base64," + results[0]
      }
    });
```

A posible explanation for this is that ImagePicker is copying from the ios gallery directory to a ImagePicker's temporary directory, then File is trying to read those copied files but they must have been deleted by iOS File System.